# async await never ends but sync runs instantly

Tags: vb.net, async-await

Code below simply checks the url of the image if it is valid or not. when I run it as below, it checks and returns instantly

```
 Function testUrl(ByVal myImage As String) As Boolean

    myHttpClient.BaseAddress = New Uri(imageUrl)
    myHttpResponse = myHttpClient.GetAsync(myImage).result

    success= myHttpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode

End Function
```

but when I run it with async-await, I dont know what happens. Because I set my break point on await line and press f10, I get no progress, I am not sure if it is because of async, it runs but I dont see any break on next line if my breakpoint is on success=myhttpresponse.issucessstatuscode line.

Url is a valid url and first code returns instantly true. Can I anyone advise what is happening?

```
 Async Function testUrl_async(ByVal myImage As String) As Task(Of Boolean)

    myHttpClient.BaseAddress = New Uri(imageUrl)
    myHttpResponse = Await myHttpClient.GetAsync(myImage)

    success= myHttpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode

End Function
```

EDIT:
when I even try the code below, it is not doing anything. But without async await works

```
 Async Function testUrl_async() As Task(Of Boolean)

         myHttpClient.BaseAddress = New Uri("http://www.logoeps.net/")
                myImage = "wp-content/uploads/2013/06/stackoverflow_logo.jpg"
         Try
           myHttpResponse = Await myHttpClient.GetAsync(myImage)

         Catch ex As Exception

End Function

        End Try
```

Comment: May be some exception? Add try/catch to see if any exception occurs or use "Break when exception is thrown" feature of visual studio. How do you call this method?

Comment: What does the rest of the app look like after the call to testUrl_async()? Are you simply exiting before the async call has had a chance to run?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel try catch doesnt catch anything. obviously no exception

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer I am looking for each imageurls and collecting broken imageurls as a list of imageurls. well basically without doing this even for a simple 1 call it doesnt work. see my edit. please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're running into a [common deadlock issue](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that I describe on my blog. Further up your call stack you probably have a call to `Task.Wait()` or `Task<T>.Result`. This can cause a deadlock.

When `Await` pauses its methods, it first captures a "context". This "context" is `SynchronizationContext.Current` (unless it is `null`, in which case it's `TaskScheduler.Current`). If you're not familiar with `SynchronizationContext`, this just means that it captures the UI context if running on a UI thread, an ASP.NET request context if it's running on an ASP.NET request thread, or the thread pool context (unless you're using some other context). This captured context is used to resume the `Async` method.

Later, when the awaitable completes (in this case, an HTTP Get), the `Async` method attempts to resume execution. However, if the calling code has *blocked* the UI thread / ASP.NET request thread, then the method cannot execute in that context. So the context thread is blocked, waiting for the `Async` method to complete, and the `Async` method is blocked, waiting for the context to be free. Deadlock.

The best way to avoid this deadlock is as I describe in my [MSDN article on async best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx): 
use `Async` all the way. In other words, replace any calls to `Task.Wait()` and `Task<T>.Result` with `Await`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example works because accessing the `Result` of a `Task` will **block** the current thread until `Result` is set. Luckily it would appear that `HttpClient.GetAsync()` uses a different thread (or more likely I/O completion port) to do its work, otherwise your app would deadlock. It's generally a bad idea to block on async methods for this reason.

Changing to `await` in the second example means that the current thread will **not** block on the result. Instead it will queue up the rest of the function to be run when the result is set. At this point the code following the call to `testUrl_async()` will be run. If you simply exit at this point, the queued continuation of `testUrl_async()` will never have a chance to run.